Give an example of a set of irrationals that have a rational supremum
Problem: Give an example of a set of irrational numbers in the real line that have a rational supremum.
Proof: Consider the following set $I := \{p : \frac{-1}{\sqrt{p}} < 0, \text{where $p$ is a prime} \}$. Clearly, $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{p}}$ is irrational for each prime $p$ and converges to $0$ as $p$ blows up. Thus, the set has no largest irrational number and is bounded above by $0$. In fact, one can show that $0$ is the supremum of the set $I$ which is rational. Hence, proven.
Is it true that this fraction is always irrational for each prime $p$? I am not quite convinced though. Is it necessary to show that $0$ is the supremum of the set as it is clear from the proof?
Edit: The proof is essentially correct and the proof that each in the set I is irrational is given below by the well-known argument.

$]0,1[ \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ would be quicker no?

1/ Yes it's true. How can you prove it? $\quad$ 2/With your ideas here, there's a much simpler answer. Hint: How do you find a set of rationals with an irrational supremum?

Consider the set of rationals satisfying $x^2 < 2?$

@julio_es_sui_glace I think it also works as you throw out the measure set zero.

@BrianMoehring thanks for the catch! Appreciated!

Your set (in your comment) contains only rationals

@Gradmath That's a great set for my hint. Now completely swap around all of the terms irrational $\leftrightarrow$ rational. What would a similar set be?

I first learned about the Real Numbers constructed via Dedekind cuts from GH Hardy's Pure Mathematics. That is worth noting in relation to this problem, I think. It provides a different way of thinking about the Real Numbers eg see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut

Besides examples already given --- the set of negative irrational numbers.

Even simpler.. $\big{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\big} $.

"Consider the set of rationals satisfying $x^2<2$"  Why not consider the set of irrationals so that $ x^2 < 4$?  @julio_es_sui_glace said it yesterday and it is still true, the simplest set might be "the set of all positive irrationals less than $1$".  It's bound below by $0$.  And for any value more than $0$ there is an irrational less than it.  So $\inf (]0,1[\setminus \mathbb Q) = 0$.

Okay... I'm one-upping @julio_es_sui_glace.  Consider "the set of all negative irrationals".  Can't get much simpler than that (.... although, I won't be surprised if someone here tries ... I'd be surprised if they succeeded but, not all that surprised.)

Please, avoid using MathJax for non-math expressions. It can hinder the search engine of the site.

Yes, $-1/\sqrt{p}$ is irrational for every prime $p$. To see this, it suffices to show that $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational for a prime $p$. It is a well-known argument.
Suppose otherwise; then $\sqrt{p} = n/m$ for some positive integers $m, n$. We may assume $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Now observe that
$$
n^2 = m^2 p
$$
holds. The left-hand side is a multiple of $p$, and since $p$ is prime, $n$ must be a multiple of $p$. So write $n = pn'$ for some $n' \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Now
$$
pn'^2 = m^2
$$
so by the same reasoning, $m$ is also a multiple of $p$, which contradicts that $m$ and $n$ were coprime. Hence the proof is done.
